# Find joint distribution of dependent indicator functions

Tags: probability

Given two random indicator random variables, $I_A$ and $I_B$, each with the given probability $P(I_A = 1) = p_A, P(I_A = 0) = 1-p_A, P(I_B = 1) = p_B, P(I_B = 0) = 1-p_B$. Furthermore, the conditional probability $ P(I_B = 1 | I_A = 1) = q $ is known. Is it possible to determine the joint probability for all events with this information?

Using Bayes, $P(I_A, I_B) = P(I_B | I_A) P(I_A)$, so $P(I_A = 1, I_B =0)$ and $P(I_A = 1, I_B =1)$  can be calculated. But what can be said about $P(I_A = 0, I_B =0)$ and $P(I_A = 0, I_B =1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can derive all of the missing values by considering the total probabilities of $I_A$ and $I_B$. For example, $P(I_A = 1) = P(I_A = 1, I_B = 1) + P(I_A = 1, I_B = 0)$.